# SQL DLETE Statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a customized application in my company where I can create a place for users to input their values to a database. 
The table where I am submitting the data has 5 columns with its SQL CREATE Query as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log_Ongoing](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogType] [int] NULL,
    [ActivityDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ActivityDescription] [text] NULL,
    [Train] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log_Ongoing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log_Ongoing]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_Ongoing_Trains] FOREIGN KEY([Train])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trains] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log_Ongoing] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_Ongoing_Trains]
GO
```

The purpose of this table is to record the ongoing activities in the plant.
The user can come later and modify those activities by updating, adding or deleting through the application by choosing the report data then modifying the data.
My thinking was that before the user submits the data I will delete the old data with the same report date first then insert the new data again. 
Unfortunately the data is submitted successfully, but not deleted.

I made a SQL trace to check the queries that the application sends to the database, and I found the below two statements:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM Log_Ongoing WHERE ActivityDate = @StartDate',N'@startDate datetimeoffset(7)',@startDate='2017-02-12 07:00:00 +02:00'

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Log_Ongoing (LogType, ActivityDate, ActivityDescription, Train ) VALUES (1,@StartDate, @Activity, @Train)',N'@Train int,@Activity nvarchar(2),@startDate datetimeoffset(7)',@Train=1,@Activity=N'11',@startDate='2017-02-12 07:00:00 +02:00'
```

When I tested the INSERT staement in the SSMS, it worked fine, but then when I tested the DELETE statement, it didn't work. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this `but then when I tested the DELETE statement, it didn't work`

Comment: If `DELETE` doesn't delete anything, it's because there is no matching record to delete. Did you try the statement *after* inserting the new record? Try changing `DELETE` to `SELECT COUNT(*)`, do you get any matches?

Comment: PS `ActivityDate` is just a `datetime`, not a `datetimeoffset(7)`. Whatever you enter to the table wil be truncatet to `datetime`'s precision

Comment: If you are deleting only one record at a time then you can use the ID only because it is the PK of the table.

Comment: I tried the DELETE statement in the SSMS with data in the table that matches the date and it didn't work.

Comment: @Panagiotis Regarding the ActivityDate column it has to be datetime data type as the application doesn't have that data type. When the application is creating the INSERT statement it is already assigning the variable "startdate" as datetimeoffset(7) with a value that is not datetimeoffset(7). I will try to convert the "startdate" to datetime datat type in the DELETE statement.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: It worked when I converted the variable data type as below:

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM Log_Ongoing WHERE ActivityDate = CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)',N'@startDate datetimeoffset(7)',@startDate='2017-02-12 07:00:00 +02:00'

Comment: You need to clean up the queries. There's no point in passing a datetimeoffset if the underlying type is datetime. This *forces* an offset conversion to local time at the database level. Why are you using `sp_executesql` to execute queries anyway? You can declare variables in T-SQL too

Comment: Try `exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM Log_Ongoing WHERE ActivityDate = @StartDate',N'@startDate datetime',@startDate='2017-02-12 07:00:00'` or `declare @StartDate datetime='2017-02-12 07:00:00'; delete from Log_Ongoing WHERE ActivityDate =@StartDate`

Comment: BTW, if you use ADO.NET to execute a parameterized query you don't need `sp_executesql`. Just write the query with the parameter and pass the parameter value

Comment: On the other hand, if you create a SQL string using string manipulation, you are just as vulnerable to SQL Injection whether you use `sp_executesql` or not. Parameterized queries send parameters *outside* the *entire* query string, as part of the RPC call. A query string that contains a `sp_executesql` call and parametersis though, still a query string. A single `"` character in the input will still allow injection attacks.

Comment: @AmrMagdy which language are you using to build the application? Why don't you use proper parameterized queries? Why do you pass the date as a `datetimeoffset` string if the application doesn't support such a value. Are you using FreeTDS perhaps?

Comment: No I am not using a specific language. I just input the query in the application and it does the rest of it. The application is creating the datetimeoffset variable and passing the report value to it. It passes the query to the database through XML. I fount that in the application log.

Comment: The application is creating the sp_executesql command.